# Unable to run docker Hello-World

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Docker Newbie here!

I installed the docker community edition following this instruction (https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#start-docker-for-windows)
however I'm getting the error for running hello-world

```
PS C:\Users\ahkim> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:nanoserver' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: how do i check?

Comment: Likely a network or proxy issue. If there's a proxy, it should be configured as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon